# How to loop various conditions multiple times

Tags: sensors, programming-languages

I have 2 arrays (s_left and s_right) a length (dis), the arrays in reality are produced from sensor values.

The first situation entails looping the condition (s_left < dis) twice and at the same time looping (s_right < dis) once.

Is there a method to specify the number of times a individual condition can be looped through whilst preforming various conditions? The coding is in Java and **I am not convinced the method attempted below is correct**

```
public class test {
    public void test() {
        double s_right[] = new double[]{10, 13, 14, 15};
        double s_left[] = new double[]{12.6, 14, 18, 18};

        double dis = 12.5;

        for (int i = 0; i < s_left.length; i++) {
            if (s_left[i] < dis) {
                for (int j = 0; j < s_left.length; j++) {
                    if ((s_left[j] < dis) && (s_right[i] < dis)) {
                        System.out.println("working!!!");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: make the first comparison `if ((s_left[i] < dis) && (s_right[i] < dis)) {`  ..... make the second comparison `if (s_left[j] < dis) {`

Comment: So, I am trying to preform.... if (s_left[j] < dis) ....twice and at the same time preform the loop.... if (s_right[i] < dis).... twice, upon looping and verifying the loop statement is shall print ....System.out.println("working!!!");.....Hope this makes sence?

Comment: This was my first attempt, I looped the (s_left[j] < dis) once then within the condition looped again but I think this will not work. the purpose is to verify the (s_left[j] < dis) twice before making the robot commence on its path. Same idea with the right side.

Comment: @jsotola would you have any idea how to run the loop twice before making the robot move forward?

Comment: why would you want to check the same numbers twice? ... that seems pointless

Comment: Because depending on the robots location running twice will verify if the robot has encounted an object I am designing to avoid or just a slight interference

Comment: you are not updating the data ... the result will be the same both times .... anyway, just use another `for` loop that repeats twice